# Has someone any idea creating locations for microposts with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

I wanna add check in columns to microposts and  stores microposts based on our current location, shows nearby check-ins, and displays check-ins on a map.

Is it necessary to change my database from sqlite to mysql or postgresql?

Which gems you prefer? What am I starting with?

Comment: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder

Comment: You are really become my teacher @AndreyDeineko .. I'm new at rails and I tried to learn myself. I finished Michael Hartl Rails exercises and now your advices are really useful for me. Thanks again for everything...

Comment: if this is what you were looking for, I can add it as an answer so you can accept it:)

Comment: Yes, you can add it, I'll accept :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the conversation in comments, [geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) seem to be one of the most used gems for geolocation stuff in Rails.